The real part of the Stieltjes transform.
Suppose that $\mu$ is a probability measure with pdf f. Consider the Stieltjes transform of $\mu$ being $$G(z) = \int\frac{\mu(d\tau)}{\tau -z}.$$ We know that the imaginary part of $G(z)$ has an explanation as the density of the convolution of a Cauchy density and the density of $\mu$. We can get the density of $\mu$ by considering the imaginary part near the real line.
What about the real part? Can it happen that as $z$ approaches the real line, the real part of $G(z)$ is unbounded?
